# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = 'update' is not creating table cause table exist in another database. what could be the reason

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following is JPA hibernate configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
           class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
           <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="*****" />
           <property name="jpaProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
               </props>
           </property>
       </bean>
```

Following Datasource in tomcat 7 server.xml file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/Pool"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"             
              username="root"
              password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cc_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
              testWhileIdle="true"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="false"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              validationInterval="30000"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              maxActive="100"
              minIdle="10"
              maxWait="10000"
              initialSize="10"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              logAbandoned="true"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
              maxTotal="10"
              maxIdle="10"
              maxWaitMillis="10000"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="300"           
              defaultAutoCommit="true" />
```

following are the log that is generating in the catlina.log file, I have trimmed the log to highlight my point

```
2021-09-16 18:54:48,084 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - HHH000261: Table found: cc_db.table_abc
2021-09-16 18:54:48,084 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2021-09-16 18:54:48,084 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
2021-09-16 18:54:48,156 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] - HHH000261: Table found: cc_db_back.table_def
```

So 'table_def' is not creating in 'cc_db' cause it exits in my backup 'cc_db_back' database.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I see you are only configuring a DataSource for 'cc_db'. Where are you configuring a DataSource for 'cc_db_back' database?

Comment: No no,  with the root user account in MySQL 8, I have multiple Databases cc_db, cc_db_backup, test, sample. But If the table exists in any of these DB except cc_db which I have configured in the data source file.  hbm2ddl doesn't create a table in the cc_db table and log print like I have shared.

Comment: I see the Datasource is configured to use 'cc_db', where does 'cc_db_back' database is configured in the application?

Comment: Sir, this is what I am saying, I have not configured 'cc_db_backup' anywhere. this is the reason why I have asked these questions.
Rest I have already explained.
Even table exists in another database as I have mentioned list of databases like test or sample. the required table is not creating in the database cc_db which I have configured in source file

Comment: Can you try using new MySQL database 'sampledb', and different MySQL user user1/user1passwd. Please make sure the new user user1 has access restricted to only sampledb databases. This will help to isolate the mis configuration from app.